# WSO2 API Manager 1.8 with WSO2 BAM 2.5 - Clustered Environment

Tags: java, mysql, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm using 2 instances of WSO2 API Manager 1.8. Each instance is deployed on an Ubuntu instance and fronted with a HAProxy load balancer. I have configured to run API Manager with MySQL. For the reporting purpose I have integrated WSO2 BAM 2.5 on a diffrent instance. IPs are as follows.

```
HAProxy -> 192.168.11.1
API Manager 1 -> 192.168.11.2
API Manager 2 -> 192.168.11.3
MySQL -> 192.168.11.4
BAM -> 192.168.11.5
```

On API Manager 1 reports are shown correctly but not in the API Manager 2. I have followed the same configuration on both API Manager 1 and API Manager 2 instances. No errors are shown in the API Manager log or BAM log as well.

How can I fix this so that reports appear on both instances of API Manager?

*Note that I have generated enough traffic to reports to be generated.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

summarized data will be in mysql stats database.so if one apimanger can get that data and display and other cannot get that data and display means probably you could have done mistake in the configuration of apimanger instance 2.

check(for apimanger 2)

1. You have correct configuration on master-datasource.xml for stats db
2. You have uncommented following element according to the doc[1]. `<DataSourceName>jdbc/WSO2AM_STATS_DB</DataSourceName>`

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM180/Publishing+API+Runtime+Statistics